# Constraints on non-compactified extra dimensions

Tags: string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, branes, supergravity, compactification

I'm reading this paper

[An introduction to extra dimensions and string phenomenology](https://pos.sissa.it/263/007/pdf)

Which according to it, in string theory the 4-dimensional Plank scale is related to the Planck scale of perpendicular compactified extra dimensions by

$$ M_{pl}^2 \sim M^{(2+n)} R_\bot^n ,$$

where $R_\bot^n$ is the volume of these extra dimensions. Now if another model (modified supergravity) leads to an alternative relation

$$ M_{pl}^2 \sim M^{(2+n)} R_\parallel^n, $$

where in this time $R_\parallel^n$ is the volume of the parallel- not compactified - extra dimensions ( see Fig. 1 ) . For $n=1$ the last equation becomes:

$$ M_{pl}^2 \sim M^3 R_\parallel. \tag{2} $$

The question is there any constraints on the volume of the bulk or the parallel  - not compactified - extra dimension? First of all, it can not be infinite to have a well-defined $M_{pl}$, also I think it can't be small of order Planck length, or millimeters because it is not compactified and large.

If one assumes $M_{pl} \sim 10^{18}$ GeV, and M say of order electroweak scale $\sim 1000$ GeV, one will get $ R_\parallel \sim 10^7 \text{cm} \sim 10^8 \text{mm} $ ( to solve the hierarchy problem) , so is this a consistent prediction? Will that be consistent with Newton's gravity? If not how we can assume appropriate scales in Equ. (2)?

Any help is appreciated!